# What semantic notions underlie 'octopus or cuttlefish' with 'nasal tumours'?

Tags: etymology

> [polyp (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=polyp)
>       c. 1400, "nasal tumor,"
>   from Middle French polype and
>   directly from Latin polypus "cuttlefish," also "nasal tumor,"
>   from Greek (Doric, Aeolic) polypos "octopus, cuttlefish,"
>   from polys "many" (from PIE root [*pele-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=*pele-&allowed_in_frame=0) (1) "to fill") + pous "foot" (from PIE root [*ped-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=*ped-&allowed_in_frame=0) "foot"). Etymological sense revived 1742 as a name for hydras and sea anemones (earlier polypus, early 16c.). The Latin word is the source of French poulpe "octopus."

To me, [nasal tumours](https://www.google.com/search?q=octopus+nasal+tumour&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimk8XJ86XUAhWIWSYKHba2A9YQ_AUIBigB&biw=1152&bih=538#tbm=isch&q=nasal+tumour) do not resemble octopodes or cuttlefish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am no physician, so take this with a grain of salt.

A [polyp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyp_(medicine)) is an abnormal growth of tissue which may produce narrow elongated stalks.
These stalks give a good reason to describe it as "many-leg", which is what polyp means as you describe.
Polyps are common in the nose, but polyp is not synonymous with nasal tumor.
It can be regarded as a subclass of nasal tumors, but I believe polyps are found elsewhere, too.
Perhaps the earliest known occurrences were in the nasal area; that would explain it meaning only a nasal tumor centuries ago.
Most of the nasal tumors Google shows you are not polyps at all.
(I'm not sure if a polyp is classified as a tumor, but that doesn't really matter.)

As a side note, [polyp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyp) is also an animal.
It also has a multi-legged appearance.

**Conclusion:**
Anything that looks like it has many legs can reasonably be called a polyp.
There is a nasal tumor with this appearance and hence this name, but this is not the type of nasal tumors.